# How to prevent modal from showing after table contain 5 items?

Tags: javascript, laravel, html-table, bootstrap-modal

I have a time schedule table where i can add a new item on each cell of the table by clicking the corresponding cell. The user input is in the form of a modal. How can i make it so that when user have added 5 items to the cell, the modal will be inactive? can anyone help?

Here is so far I can do

```
<td data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CalenderModalNew" {{count($jad)>5 ? 'onclick="event.stopPropagation();"' : ''}}>
    @foreach ($jad as $jadu)
      {{$jadu}}
    @endforeach
</td>
```

But it doesn't stop the modal from showing